# Port 5000 is already in use during debug mode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Debug console output:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --inspect-brk=6158 bin\www 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:6158/746bda7b-b3ca-4335-9dbe-d254b0860be8
Listening on 5000
app.js:18
Port 5000 is already in use
```

Launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 5858
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\bin\\www"
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
            "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome"
        }
    ]
}
```

It works fine before this when I run the debug but somehow lately, when I tried to run it again, it keeps saying Port 5000 is already in use.

However, I am able to run my application which uses Port 5000 as well by accessing: localhost:5000. It just does not work when I tried to debug the application in debug mode.

EDIT:
Regardless of which port I use, it keeps returning port is already in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run another instance of your node app alongside an already running one, try killing it first and then run the app with the debug flag. Important to note that "debug mode" uses *another* port (defaults to 9229 alongside the port the server listens to)